# How can I change the third occurrence of a word in a file using sed?

Tags: command-line, text-processing, sed

I need to change the 3rd occurrence of 'None' in a file `text.txt` using the `sed` command. I found this command

```
sed 's/None/All/3' text.txt
```

but this works for 3rd occurrence of 'None' in a line, not in the entire document. Is there any way to use sed to look for 'None' in the entire document and change only the 3rd occurrence?

I could use the line number, but if my document changes then the command won't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given GNU sed, you can kind of fake it by adding the `-z` (or `--null-data`) option:

> ```
> -z, --null-data
>              separate lines by NUL characters
> ```

Assuming your document doesn't actually contain null-delimited data, this will cause sed to treat the whole document as a single line so that the `3` modifier assumes the meaning that you want

```
sed -z 's/None/All/3' text.txt
```

Comment: Thank you nam. it worked!!!, thank you, thank you... you are the best.